# Can't read data from Firebase database with .once() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, web-applications, firebase

I want to be able to read a piece of data from a `Firebase` database upon the `onclick` event of a button firing. From going through the documentation and such it seems the `once()` function is the way to go here, since I'm not trying to link the data reading to any specific `Firebase` event, such as adding a child, but rather when someone click a button on the page. Here is the line where I call `once()` ...

```
curPoll.once('value', function(curPollSnapshot) {
    numElections = curPollSnapshot.val().NumElections;
});
```

The problem is that I can't get the data to be read, even though `curPoll` is set to a data reference and `numElections` is a global variable in my script. numElections keeps coming back as undefined. In fact, I can't even seem to step into the function in FireBug, as though there were a syntax error. If there is a syntax error, I can't figure it out, and anyway I think the whole script wouldn't load at all in Firebug if that were the case. But be that as it may I can't step into the function to see what's going on for some reason.

Here is the function where curPoll is set...

```
function createPoll() 
{
    var pollName = $('#txtCreatePoll').val();
    if (pollName == "" || pollName == null)
    {
         alert("You must enter a name for your poll!");
         return;
    }
    else 
    {
        pollsRef = new Firebase('https://poll-database.firebaseio.com/Polls');
        //TODO add error callback
        curPoll = pollsRef.push({Name: pollName, Elections: null, NumElections: 0 });
        elections = curPoll.push();
        $('div#divCreateElections1').slideDown('slow');
    }
 }
```

As you can see the `elections` reference is pushed in here as a child of reference `curPoll`.

Here is the function where I try and read data from the elections reference....

```
            function addElection()
            {
                curPoll.once('value', function(curPollSnapshot) {
                    numElections = curPollSnapshot.val().NumElections;
                });
                var electionName = $('div#divCreateElections' + (parseInt(numElections)+1) + ' > input#txtCreateElection').val();
                var numberToElect = $('div#divCreateElections' + (parseInt(numElections)+1) + ' > input#txtNumElect').val();
                if (electionName == "" || electionName == null)
                {
                    alert("You must enter a name for your election!");
                    return;
                }
            }
```

As I said, numElections keeps coming up as undefined. Here is the basic structure of my firebase database...

```
Poll-Database > Polls > Poll1
                        Poll2
                        ...
                        Polln > Name
                              > NumElections
                              > Elections > Election1
                                          > Election2
                                          ...
                                          > Electionn
```

And just in case here's the body of my page...

```
<body>
    <div id="divCreatePoll">
        Enter Name of New Poll:
        <input type="text" id="txtCreatePoll" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        <button id="btnCreatePoll" onclick="createPoll(); return false;">CREATE POLL</button>
        <p id="pError"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="divCreateElections1">
        Enter Election Name:
        <input type="text" id="txtCreateElection" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        Enter Number of Candidates to Elect:
        <input type="text" id="txtNumElect" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        <button id="btnCreateElection" onclick="addElection(); return false;">CREATE ELECTION</button>  
        <br /><br />
        <p id="pError"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `once` is an asynchronous call. So it's not going to set `numElections` instantly. Thus, when you use numElections, it hasn't been set yet.

You just need to move the rest of the code inside the callback as well.

```
function addElection() {
   curPoll.once('value', function(curPollSnapshot) {
      numElections = curPollSnapshot.val().NumElections;
      var electionName = $('div#divCreateElections' + (parseInt(numElections)+1) + ' > input#txtCreateElection').val();
      var numberToElect = $('div#divCreateElections' + (parseInt(numElections)+1) + ' > input#txtNumElect').val();
      if (electionName == "" || electionName == null)
      {
         alert("You must enter a name for your election!");
         return;
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Yup, just figured this out a few minutes ago. Another question, is there any way to name a ref to a list that is added programmaticallly, like 

var elections = curPoll.push();

...or do you just have to use the ref and accept the randomly assigned name Firebase produces? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, got it, I should be using child() instead of push()

Comment: If you use push(), you get a `ref` back, so push().name() will get the key of the new child.